# Trying to find the name of a book with smartphone-like shoes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am looking for the title of a book I read a good while ago. Because it's been a long time since I read it. I think it was more of a children/teenage book.

- The story started with a group of gifted children on some kind of
  camping vacation on another planet.
- The protagonist was a boy of that group.
- I remember that they all had these shoes with a massive amount of electronics in it (seemed kind of like today's smartphones).
- At one point they connected all the shoes and placed them around a lake to get surround sound music.

The music was also special. It was explained that the music has (in the future) gotten so good that it went directly into the brain and you practically had to start dancing to it.